# What would have the fastest lookup for a SHA1 hashed column?

Tags: mysql, innodb, database-performance

Hashed column will be unique.

1. char(40) type
2. binary(20)type
3. Using UUID instead of sha1 hash

Engine: InnoDB

The table should contain couple of millions of rows. I'm curious on the performance hit when searching that table by the hash value, but I don't know what type to use, and which of these types supports indexing and how will they impact overall performance.

Comment: So have you created some test tables and benchmarked them? It really depends on your use case. As a note, MySQL does not have a native UUID type, it ends up being a string, and supplying 8-bit binary values as keys is *extremely* annoying.

Comment: I get the feeling UUID'd will be slower, as it'll have to find the next UUID it can use (which will only get worse as your table gets bigger). However, with such a small char length, I wonder what the collision probability would be

Comment: I haven't done any tests because of the insufficient time, The collision for sha1 is not found yet, so I'm relying on that fact.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know about UUIDs, but I'd certainly expect the `binary(20)` column to be faster than the `char(40)` column. Since the key length is shorter, I would think that makes it slightly faster to do a key comparison.

I've run a few tests that seem to confirm that theory. Only on small tables though, so your results may vary. Also, there's not a huge difference in speed - the binary version was around 4% faster at best.

Comment: I've decided to go with binary for now.